# Python pytesseract no such file or directory

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I've already looked through the readmes and existing threads. Currently running on windows 7. Installed tesser-ocr from the ub mannheim github, pip installed pytesseract. pip installed tesser-ocr as well. My code is as such:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR"

from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\my name\\Downloads\\ffs.jpg')
```

Can't get it to work. Even manually input the tesseract.exe directory into the PATH.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\my name\\Downloads\\ffs.jpg
```

any takers?

Comment: Does the ffs.jpg file exist?

Comment: Yep. It’s sitting right there in the folder

Comment: maybe you need to escape the whitespaces in your file path. Try first putting ffs.jpg under 'C:\\ffs.jpg'

Comment: earlier I shifted the file to another folder without white space in the directory. Didn’t work either. Will give it a try again anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 image = Image.open(r'C:\Users\my name\Downloads\ffs.jpg')
```

Comment: does the file exists? if exists change the file format

Comment: does     import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR"                gives any error ?

Comment: Nope. Only the image part throws an error. Googling anything about the error points it to pytesseract though which I doubt

Comment: try with other image and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188597/discussion-between-hukkemaaru-and-qonl).

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to add `tesseract.exe` to the end of my cmd string.

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\my name\\Downloads\\ffs.jpg')
```

This works.